# Cut cut cut.... the rope!

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

I have a rope and I cut it into **two different integer lengths** and gave one of them to Alice, the other one to Bob. Then I asked Alice and Bob to cut their ropes into pieces in such a way that when they multiply the length of their own rope pieces, the result shall be **the maximum**. Both did it right and got their pieces of ropes!

It is known that Bob's original rope length was **six times** than Alice's and the number of rope pieces that Bob obtained is **five times** the number that Alice had.

> What is the original length of the rope?

- They cut their own robe at least once.
- The length of the pieces is not neccessarily integer values.

Comment: The title reminded me of *Row, row, row your boat*. Was this intended? ;)

Comment: @user477343  actually no but maybe subconciously :)

Comment: I'm getting multiple solutions, is this a possibility?

Comment: @wolfram42  nope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To maximize the product of lengths, note first that

> all the pieces should be of equal length. (If you have pieces of lengths $a\pm h$ where $h\neq0$ then replacing them with two pieces of length $a$ increases the product of those two lengths from $a^2-h^2$ to $a^2$ without changing anything else.)

Now,

> if you cut a rope of length $L$ into $n$ equal pieces then the resulting product is $(L/n)^n$. It'll be convenient to take its logarithm, $n\log L-n\log n$. If we imagine varying $n$ *continuously* (which of course we can't actually do) then the derivative is $\log L-\log n-1$, which is increasing for $L/n<e$ and decreasing for $L/n>e$. So the best $n$ is either $\lfloor L/e\rfloor$ or $\lceil L/e\rceil$.

Let the lengths of rope be $a$ (for Alice) and $6a$ (for Bob). Then the optimal numbers

> are nearest approximations to $a/e$ and $6a/e$. I don't think it's possible for the ratio to be 5 (which is quite far from 6) unless we take $\lceil a/e\rceil$ and $\lfloor 6a/e\rfloor$. We also must have $a$ not too large (because as $a$ gets larger the ratio clearly $\rightarrow6$).

It turns out that

> the only values of $a$ for which that ratio is correct are 7 and 14; and the only one of these for which the floor/ceiling choices work out the right way is $a=7$.

So the original length is

> 7+42=49 units.

Comment: number of rope pieces, not length is five times

Comment: Oh, wrong way around. That's what happens when you try to rush things. Will fix.

Comment: Fixed now. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

So I ran a program simulating all values of Alice's rope from 1 to 100 and got the answer:

> 7

Meaning the original length is

> 49

Correctness:

> It can be easily verified (either manually taking values or using a program) that $(\frac{7}{3})^3$ is the optimal way to cut a rope of length 7 and $(\frac{42}{15})^{15}$ is the optimal way to cut a rope of length 42.

As for the mathematical solution, it's outlined below:

Starting out,

> Suppose Alice's rope has length $x$ and is cut into $y$ pieces $(x, y \in \mathbb{N})$. Then Bob's rope must have length $6x$ and cut into $5y$ pieces. We want to find out $x$ and $y$.

Then using some calculus:

> If we want to cut $x$ into $y$ pieces, each piece needs to have length $\frac{x}{y}$. 
> To find the optimal $y$ for a given $x$, we maximize $f(y) = (\frac{x}{y})^y$ for fixed $x$. By taking the partial derivative with respect to $y$ and equating it to $0$, we get that $x = ey$. 
>  
>  Since $y$ is an integer, we have $y = \left \lfloor{\frac{x}{e}}\right \rfloor$ or $y = \left \lfloor{\frac{x}{e}}\right \rfloor + 1$ and similarly, $5y = \left \lfloor{\frac{6x}{e}}\right \rfloor$ or $5y = \left \lfloor{\frac{6x}{e}}\right \rfloor + 1$. (At this point, I used WolframAlpha). Solving for $x$, we get $x = 7$.